BK3432-based BLE device
I have tried to create a BK3432-based ble devices, but was faced several problems. I have wrote programm base on examples from BK3432 SDK.
On the one hand I can't to put device in deep sleep mode, and on another hand I can't use SPP mode.
For the first divice I have tried to use source code from public examples like ble_app_gatt_advertising_tag and use this settings:
/// Advertising channel map - 37, 38, 39
//连接参数更新控制
#define UPDATE_CONNENCT_PARAM           1

//最小连接间隔 
#define BLE_UAPDATA_MIN_INTVALUE        8
//最大连接间隔
#define BLE_UAPDATA_MAX_INTVALUE        10
//连接Latency 
#define BLE_UAPDATA_LATENCY             0
//连接超时
#define BLE_UAPDATA_TIMEOUT             600
#define APP_ADV_CHMAP           (0x07)
#define APP_ADV_INT_MIN         (8000)
#define APP_ADV_INT_MAX         (8000)
/// Fast advertising interval
#define APP_ADV_FAST_INT        (32)


Also I used this code for put chip in deep sleep mode:
timer_enable(true);
tim_counter = timer_get_time();
icu_set_sleep_mode (0);
user_timer_init();

void user_timer_init(void)
{
  PWM_DRV_DESC timer_desc;  
  timer_desc.channel = 1;        
  timer_desc.mode    = 1<<0 | 1<<1 | 1<<2 | 0<<4;   
  timer_desc.end_value  = 65534;                      
  timer_desc.duty_cycle = 0;   
  timer_desc.p_Int_Handler = user_timer_cb;     

  REG_AHB0_ICU_PWMCLKCON |= (1<<1);
  REG_AHB0_ICU_PWMCLKCON &= ~(7<<12);
  REG_AHB0_ICU_PWMCLKCON |= (8<<12);
  pwm_init(&timer_desc);
}
void user_timer_cb(unsigned char ucChannel)
{
    cnt++;
    if((cnt > 600)&&(BACT_STATE))   
    {
        BACT_STATE = !BACT_STATE;
        cnt = 0;
    }
    if((cnt > 1200)&&(!BACT_STATE)) 
    {
        BACT_STATE = !BACT_STATE;
        cnt = 0;
    }
}

So since I can't put device in deep sleep mode, the power consumption of it is quite high.
For the second device I haven't found any examples for this chip and tried to create my own code. But I have failed.
Also I can't find any examples source code and firmware of BK3432-based bluetooth modules.
Can you help me please?
